# multiple database connection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I want my Entry model to use multiple databases. When a customer joins the network a new database is automaticly created for this customer. Other models will use same database. Is this possible in rails?

Comment: Did you google your question? This has been asked a hundred times.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=multiple+database+connection+in+rails&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I would really recommend against attempting this.  You'd need to establish a database connection for each customer, which will not scale well at all.  Is there a reason you can't store all your customers data in the same DB?

Comment: Here is api doc for connecting multiple databases at the same time. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, I just came up with a solution to this ten minutes ago...

Here goes...

First off define the separate database connection in your database.yml

mine has

```
production:
 adapter: mysql
 -etc etc-
```

Then I added an additional one (for me, I've a legacy database I want to connect to...)

```
legacy_production:
  adapter: mysql
  -etc etc-
```

Repeat this for different environments where appropriate

The next thing I did was create a new file in 'lib' called 'legacy_model.rb' and it looks quite simply like this

```
 require 'active_record'

    class LegacyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.abstract_class = true
      establish_connection "legacy_#{RAILS_ENV}"
    end
```

Now, to make use of this, I just create a class/model and inherit from LegacyModel like so...

```
class User < LegacyModel
  -any validations etc you might want-
end
```

And voila, it'll access the legacy database instead of the one I'm using.

There are probably better solutions, but this seems to work for me - hope it helps!

Comment: Oh botheration, I've *just* noticed you wanted the same model accessing multiple databases and my answer doesn't really do that! BAH! Hopefully it'll give you some sort of starting point though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there are particular architectural reason you need to use separate databases? I'd imagine a much more common solution to 'multihoming' applications like this is to store an account_id on your Entry model and have a single database.