# Rails 3.2 multiple database connections with same model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, multiple-databases

There are many questions and answers regarding the creation of multiple connections to multiple databases in rails:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480330/2120023

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6305540/2120023

Example from outside stackoverflow: http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/09/21/establishing-a-connection-to-a-non-default-database-in-rails-3-2-2/

But I have yet to find a solution that works when using a model that appears in both databases.

If my default db has a table `titles` and my `Other` db has a table `titles` how do I access the other database's Title model?

`title.rb`:

```
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

`othertitle.rb`:

```
class Other < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "other_#{Rails.env}"
end

class OtherTitle < Other
end
```

I can't use the above because I get this error (EDIT: for clarity there is no `other_titles` table in either db only a `titles` table -> EDIT 2: If I do create an `other_titles` table in the `Other` database, everything works perfectly but that does not help me access the `titles` table.):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'other.other_titles' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `other_titles`
```

I also can't use `class Title < Other` because I get a `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Title` error.

`database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_dev
  pool: 5
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db
  pool: 5
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock


other_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: other_dev
  pool: 5
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

other_production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: other
  pool: 5
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: did you create appropriate database connection configs on you database.yml file for nasa_#{dev} ?

Comment: Yes, but the example technically should have `other_` and not `nasa_` I'll edit it to show correct code.

Comment: post your database.yml file pls.

Comment: @Kaldybaev added `database.yml` as requested.

Comment: as per your database file, you have four environments, each envt can use same or different database. what is creating the issue or may be i didn't get it properly. Have you checked with this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

Comment: @GhostRider I do not have any problem connecting to the databases I choose. If I create an `other_titles` table in the `Other` database, everything works perfectly. The issue is that I cannot access the `titles` table in the `Other` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and it is quite simple:

```
class OtherTitle < Other
  self.table_name='titles'
end
```

Referenced here:

[Efficient way to pull data from second database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533393/efficient-way-to-pull-data-from-second-database/16685353#16685353)

and here:

[Cannot connect to two postgres databases in rails 3.2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679573/cannot-connect-to-two-postgres-databases-in-rails-3-2)